# Binding in WinForms where DateMember's path has multiple layers

Tags: c#, winforms, mvvm, binding, datamember

Common binding works fine in WinForms, but I have a problem if my binding's datamember has multiple layers.

I bound the TextBox's Text-Property to the property 'CurrentText' of my SubViewModel.

- When the property "CurrentText" on SubViewModel changes then all is working fine.
- When the property "SubViewModel" changes then the view reacts and updates their state correctly. But sadly the binding to "CurrentText" behaves like a "one-way" binding instead two-way.

Here is my problematic binding:

```cs
myTextBox.DataBindings.Add(nameof(myTextBox.Text), MyViewModel, "SubViewModel.CurrentText", true, DataSourceUpdateMode.OnPropertyChanged, null);
```

I think the problematic part is the third parameter *"SubViewModel.CurrentText"*.

- Can anyone say if there is a bug in WinForms for "relative"-binding (or multi-layer-binding)
- Or do I use it wrong?

*By the way. Both properties (SubViewModel and CurrentText) raises "INotifyPropertyChanged" when the setter is called.*

Thank you for the effort!

Comment: If `SubViewModel` is a Property of `MyViewModel`, then the two-way binding will work.  `SubViewModel` can be an instance of a child Class of `MyViewModel`, which exposes the public `CurrentText` property (this property raises `INotifyPropertyChanged` notifications). If `SubViewModel` is instead the name of a Class, child of `MyViewModel`, then it won't work. BTW, you're setting `true` to specify that formatting is enabled but you're not providing a Format nor a Binding object that can perform formatting (through Binding events).

Comment: Because of the enabled formatting. You are correct, the last null paremter is not required. But a true formatting is required, otherwise null values throws exceptions.

Comment: Then use a Binding object directly (e.g., `var binding = new Binding(nameof(..), ...).  binding.Format += (s, ev) => { ' Do format data-in  }; binding.Parse += (s, ev) => { ' Do format data-out  }; myTextBox.DataBindings.Add(binding);`). But this is not related to the question itself.

Comment: I created an example project on GitHub for my core problem: 
https://github.com/Der-Kraken/Kraken.WinFormsBinding.

Addittionaly I have opened an ticket at MS because the example code is large: 
https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/27e6c2d9-97c4-4a96-af14-51fb7f332fb1/binding-with-multilayerdatamember-is-corrupt-in-winforms?forum=winformsdatacontrols

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution which works. The second Binding-Parameter "dataSource" (MyViewModel) should not be from any type but from "BindingSource". After wrapping MyViewModel into BindingSource all works fine.

```cs
var bindingSource = new BindingSource(this, nameof(MyViewModel));
myTextBox.DataBindings.Add(nameof(myTextBox.Text), bindingSource, "SubViewModel.CurrentText", true, DataSourceUpdateMode.OnPropertyChanged, null);
```

The solution works but only for one layer (e.g. "**SubViewModel.CurrentText**").
If there is a third layer then it don't work again (e.g. "**SubViewModel.SubSubViewModel.CurrentText**").

Has anyone an idea?

```cs
var bindingSource = new BindingSource(this, nameof(MyViewModel));
myTextBox.DataBindings.Add(nameof(myTextBox.Text), bindingSource, "SubViewModel.SubSubViewModel.CurrentText", true, DataSourceUpdateMode.OnPropertyChanged, null);
```

**Update from 16-04-2020:**

I solved the problem with a custom workaround now.

Using BindingSource as DataSource supports a two-layered-path binding. But it suffers for three layers or more. To detect changes in this case I observing that members manually now.

My solution observates the bound values on ViewModel. If any property has changed then the Method **ResetBindings** is called on **BindingSource** (see code behind of **MainView**).

I share my workaround with you in a separate branch (**CustomWorkaround**) on github:

https://github.com/Der-Kraken/Kraken.WinFormsBinding/commit/08412e9bc05e6430e4f9624a29b6efe9e98675bd

Comment: Another approach is to use WPF ;)

Comment: That's a very good idea but the project not allow it atm. But new parts should be designed that they can migrate to a potential next gen plattform like Blazor (that part are the ViewModel's which are realized with dot.net Standard).